# Java platform plugin do not use all dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, maven-bom

#### Intro

The following situation:

I'm working on multiple dependent Java projects that are built using the Gradle build system.

There are several dependencies that I want to be resolved via the java platform plugin for gradle and a resulting BOM (Bill of Materials).

#### Example & Problem:

In the example below there is a `build.gradle` for the platform BOM that is used as a dependency resolver for all projects. There are two constraints in this BOM: One for an implementation dependency named `foo` an another for compile dependency named `bar`.

```
// build.gradle for BOM "my-utility-bom"
// ...
dependencies {
    constraints {
        api("some.implementation.dependency:foo:3.4.1")
        api("some.compile.dependency:bar:1.2.0")
    }
}
// ...
```

Both dependencies are then used inside a project by applying the platform keyword to the given bom project. Because I would like to use the two contraints from the bom as dependencies, I then use `implementation` on the platform project and `compileOnly` the same way.

```
// build.gradle for java project
//...
dependencies {
    implementation(platform(project(":my-utility-bom")))
    compileOnly(platform(project(":my-utility-bom")))

    implementation("some.implementation.dependency:foo")
    compileOnly("some.compile.dependency:bar")
}

// ...
```

After that, all dependencies are pulled in as both, a `implementation` dependency AND `compileOnly` dependency. But I just want the one depenency as an `implementation` dependency and the other as a `compileOnly` dependency.

#### Question

Is possible to only pull specific dependencies as `implementation` or `compileOnly` dependency without the use of separate BOMs for compile and implementation dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out an example similar to yours and dependencies get resolved as expected.
In your case when running `gradle dependencies`:

- implementation configuration will import only `some.implementation.dependency:foo`
- compileOnly configuration will import `some.compile.dependency:bar`

Then this will be resolved in

- `compileClasspath` importing both resolved dependencies `some.implementation.dependency:foo:3.4.1`  and `some.compile.dependency:bar:1.2.0`
- `runtimeClasspath` will import only `some.implementation.dependency:foo:3.4.1`

I would say that your configuration is correct. In case your dependency tree say otherwise, then maybe there are dependencies applied somehow additionally not visible from your example. Would be helpful to see your actual case. Note I used Gradle 7.0. In this repository [there is whole example](https://github.com/rivancic/gradle-sandbox/tree/master/maven-bom).

This [graph helped](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) me understand how different configuration will be resolved